# Use git "log" from another folder

Tags: git

I am in directory `A`. How do I execute `git log` for the git repository in directory `B`?

Comment: With git 1.8.5 (Q4 2013), you will have another choice, instead of setting `--git-dir`: see [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20115753/6309)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git pull while not in a git directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083224/git-pull-while-not-in-a-git-directory)

Comment: `(cd ../other/dir && git log)` - just enclosed in round brackets, this runs a new subshell so after returning you end up in the original location.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I execute a Git command without being in the repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7149984/how-do-i-execute-a-git-command-without-being-in-the-repository)

Answer (score 254, accepted):

From, `man git`:

You can do this with the `--git-dir` parameter, before passing any commands.

```
git --git-dir /foo/bar/.git log
```

(Specifying the `.git` directory is necessary.) From the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#git---git-dirltpathgt):

> `--git-dir=<path>`
>
> Set the path to the repository. This can also be controlled by setting the `GIT_DIR` environment variable. It can be an absolute path or relative path to current working directory.

Comment: You have to reference the `.git` directory. Try `git --git-dir=/foo/bar/.git log`.

Comment: sorry, my wrong you don't put the = between --git-dir and directory name. so it becomes git --git-dir /foo/bar log

Comment: Warning! This approach is broken for operations other than `log`. Try `git --git-dir /foo/someclone/.git status` - git gets totally confused. I recommend `-C` as noted below.

Comment: I have yet to come across a git help page that includes the string "--git-dir" :'(

Comment: @thinsoldier `man git` does on my system (2.3.5). But @VonC answer works much better.

Answer (score 226):

With [git 1.8.5 (Q4 2013)](https://github.com/git/git/blob/5fd09df3937f54c5cfda4f1087f5d99433cce527/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.5.txt#L115-L116), you will have another choice, instead of setting `--git-dir`.
If you want to execute `git log` in folder `B`, type:

```
git -C B log
```

> Just like "`make -C <directory>`", **"`git -C <directory> ...`" tells Git to go there before doing anything else**.

---

See [commit 44e1e4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/44e1e4d67d5148c245db362cc48c3cc6c2ec82ca) by **[Nazri Ramliy](http://perlresume.org/NAZRI)**:

> It takes more keypresses to invoke git command in a different directory without leaving the current directory:
>
> 1. `(cd ~/foo && git status)
>
>      git --git-dir=~/foo/.git --work-tree=~/foo status
>
>      GIT_DIR=~/foo/.git GIT_WORK_TREE=~/foo git status`
> 2. `(cd ../..; git grep foo)`
> 3. `for d in d1 d2 d3; do (cd $d && git svn rebase); done`
>
> The methods shown above are acceptable for scripting but are too cumbersome for quick command line invocations.
>
> With this new option, the above can be done with fewer keystrokes:
>
> 1. `git -C ~/foo status`
> 2. `git -C ../.. grep foo`
> 3. `for d in d1 d2 d3; do git -C $d svn rebase; done`

Comment: This is a much more reliable approach and works for commands other than `log`.

Comment: wow, and nothing in the man page! What a shame. (ok, now I see it added in 2.7 man page)

Comment: Sadly, this is still not quite as nice as Mercurial's `-R` option, since it messes up relative paths. For instance, if I type `git -C subdir log subdir/myfile` it gives an error (since it looks for the file `subdir/subdir/myfile`).

Comment: --git-dir is handier when you do something like this:
`for p in (find . -type d -name ".git"); do git --git-dir $p ...; done`

Comment: @jwd: I'm not sure how that's a problem? What you quoted is the precise behaviour I would expect, and I wouldn't want `git` to think it was cleverer than me and what I typed. If I say 'run this in directory X', I don't mean 'except sometimes, do something else'.

Comment: @underscore_d: It's just a bit of inconvenience, IMO. I don't think it's a particularly clever or unexpected idea: If I give a command the path to a file (perhaps using tab-completion to get the name easily), I would expect that command to know what file I'm talking about, even if it might have a different name relative to its enclosing repo.

Comment: I tried this using for-each-ref and it failed on me :/ standard commands seem to work find tho. Command: `git -c ~/projects/my-project for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' refs/heads/` Error: `error: key does not contain a section: ~/projects/my-project`

Comment: @JacksonBlankenship `-c` would not be right (it is for setting config); `-C` would (it it  to change path)

Comment: @VonC wow that worked, thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 7):

All possible options:

- [`-C <path>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt--Cltpathgt): Runs command as if git were started in `<path>`.
- [`--git-dir=<path>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt---git-dirltpathgt): Sets the path to the ".git" directory.
- [`--work-tree=<path>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt---work-treeltpathgt): Sets path to the working tree.

Usually, `-C` is what most people want. For other uses, consider combining the above.