# Git post-receive hook clone successful, but reporting 'not a git repository'?

Tags: git, hook, githooks

I have a `post-receive` hook inside a Git repository that clones the repository into another directory and then `cd`s into that directory.

```
#!/bin/bash --login

GIT_REPO="$HOME/oliverjash.me.git"

source "$HOME/.bash_profile"

checkout () {
  BRANCH="$1"
  TMP_GIT_CLONE="$2"

  git clone $GIT_REPO $TMP_GIT_CLONE
  cd $TMP_GIT_CLONE
  git status
}

checkout master "$HOME/tmp/oliverjash.me"
checkout project "$HOME/tmp/project.oliverjash.me"

exit
```

If I run this script whilst logged in to SSH, `git status` works fine. However, when the script is executed as the `post-receive` hook, `git status` reports this:

```
remote: fatal: Not a git repository: '.'
```

I can't understand why this is!

Comment: If you `echo $(pwd)` before `git status` is it the directory you expect?  If it is, is there a git repository in that directory?

Comment: Yes, I do, and if I run `ls -la` I can clearly see `.git`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to be sure the git command will run properly, you can add:

- `--work-tree=$TMP_GIT_CLONE`
- `--git-dir=$TMP_GIT_CLONE/.git`

That way, the git commands will know where is the working tree and the git repo to consider.

```
git --work-tree=... --git-dir=... clone ...
```

Or, since git 1.8.5, as detailed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20115753/6309):

```
git -C=$TMP_GIT_CLONE clone ...
```

Comment: Interesting. How come it doesn't just use the repository that is in the CWD?

Comment: @OliverJosephAsh because the the `GIT_DIR` is set at the execution of the script, not at the `cd` done within the script. But setting both working tree and git dir explicitly is always preferable in scripts/hooks: no ambiguity there.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do `unset GIT_DIR` at the top of the script.