# How to change directory and run git commands using PHPseclib?

Tags: php, git, phpseclib

I'm trying to use PHPseclib to SSH and run commands on the remote server. I want to change directory and commands like git pull or clone. Is there a way to do this? I know that "cd" doesn't work well with exec. So any alternatives to this?
Thanks

Comment: You could use the interactive mode. eg. $ssh->read() / $ssh->write()

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to change folder, only to specify it to your git command.

```
git --git-dir=/path/to/repo/.git --work-tree=/path/to/repo remote add xxx
git --git-dir=/path/to/repo/.git --work-tree=/path/to/repo pull
```

Since git 1;8.5 (if your server hasd a recent enough git version installed), you even can use the short version ([detailed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20115753/6309))

```
git -C /path/to/repo remote add xxx
git -C /path/to/repo pull
```

Comment: Am trying to use the git submodule update command which apparently doesn't seem to work with --git-dir. Any other alternatives? Thanks!

Comment: @AnanthakrishnanRavi then the `-C` option should work. You need to be at the root folder of the parent repo (the one declaring the submodules, and including the submodule folders)