# git init, add, commit from a different directory

Tags: git, cd, working-directory

I am writing a Lua script that creates a directory, creates some files inside of it and initializes git, adding those files to it and finally committing everything. However there's no way to use `cd` from inside Lua (you can, but it won't have effect), so I wonder if it's possible to `git init` a directory, `git add` some files and finally `git commit -a -m "message"`, all while the working directory is the directory above the desired directory.

Edit: `-C` works, thanks everyone. For anyone wondering, in Lua, `cd` "resets" after the call to `os.execute` ends. So, `os.execute("cd mydir"); os.execute("git init");` won't work as expected. To get it to work, use `os.execute("cd mydir; git init;");`.

Comment: So the git repo is in a subdirectory of the location of the lua script. Is that correct?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Exactly.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3769137/use-git-log-command-in-another-folder) is specific to `git log`, but see if the `--git-dir` flag works for other commands.

Comment: And [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083224/git-pull-while-not-in-a-git-directory) uses the `-C` flag with `git pull`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By following the hint in the comments about -C I did:

```
git init newStuff
Initialized empty Git repository in c:/fw/git/initTest/newStuff/.git/
```

to make the git repo in dir newStuff (which I had already created)

Then I added two files to newStuff, and from it's parent using using -C

```
git -C newStuff/ status
On branch master

Initial commit

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        new1
        new2

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

I see the new files.  Now add and commit them:

```
git -C newStuff/ add .
git -C newStuff/ status
On branch master

Initial commit

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)

        new file:   new1
        new file:   new2

git -C newStuff/ commit -m"initial"
[master (root-commit) bfe387b] initial
 2 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 new1
 create mode 100644 new2
```

Answer (score 6):

Example on shell:

```
#!/bin/sh
dirPath=some/dir/path
mkdir -p $dirPath
touch $dirPath/newFile
git init $dirPath
git -C $dirPath add .
git -C $dirPath commit -a -m "Initial commit"
git -C $dirPath log
```