# How to run command on each file modified in the local commits after git push?

Tags: git, githooks

I have many local commits which contains several modified files.

I need to run a specific command on each file modified after pushing to the repository, and this has to be done on the client side itself.

How do I configure git to do the same?

`git log --name-only --format="" --author xxxx origin/master..HEAD | sort | uniq`

The above command gives me all my committed files but with path relative to my repo. I need either the absolute path from the root or one which is relative to my current directory.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to run a specific command on each file modified after pushing
>   to the repository, and this has to be done on the client side itself.

You can use the [`post-receive`](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#post-receive) hook for this.

> The above command gives me all my committed files but with path
>   relative to my repo. I need either the absolute path from the root or
>   one which is relative to my current directory.

You can use the [`readlink`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/Linux/1/readlink/) utility to get an absolute path.

```
readlink -f ./relativePath
```

In your pipeline, use `xargs` so the file path is passed to `readlink`:

```
git log --name-only --format="" --author xxxx origin/master..HEAD | sort | uniq | xargs readlink -f
```

Comment: This only works when I execute it from my repo root (since the path which i get from `git log --name-only --format="" --author xxxx origin/master..HEAD | sort | uniq` is relative to the root.
Otherwise readlink give the following error which executed with -v
readlink: foo/bar/xxx.py: No such file or directory

Comment: Where is this being executed from?

Comment: From a subdirectory inside the repo. For eg. if my repo starts from foo, i execute it from foo/bar

Comment: The command I pasted above seems to work the same from anywhere within a Git repo, but you can explicitly specify to run a command from a particular git repo with the `--git-dir` option. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3769137/use-git-log-command-in-another-folder

Comment: BTW, I'm running this on Ubuntu, so perhaps the path situation is different for the platform you are on...

Comment: I'm running it on a bash shell in redhat linux. Still throwing the `No such file or directory` error. I can probably do a hack to `cd` to the start of the repo and execute this, that should work...